# How to get list of my site user

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I have a form that contains an element of type SPUser like this picture :
[image]

It's a combox witch contains the name of SPUser.Does any one have an idea.

I am using SharePoint foundation 2013.

Comment: Please add more details to the question. Are you looking to populate all users available in site? Post relevant code which gives you the current screen.

Comment: I need to create a combobox witch contain SPUser's name.

Comment: if you want to fill it dinamically, you can access through SPWeb.AllUsers or SPWeb.Users, this will return a SPUserCollection,then loop it and get SPUser.Name

Comment: this is with REST API : _api/web/siteUsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSOM for getting all site users, use following example

```
var collListItem;
function GetAllUsers()
{
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = clientContext.get_web();
    var userInfoList = web.get_siteUserInfoList();
    collListItem = userInfoList.getItems();
    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args)
{
    //Iterate through CollListItem and fill the combobox
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args)
{
    alert('Failed');
}
```